# "Tech Stack" button for nonexistent tech stack

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, companies-page

On a company's page where no tech stack is specified, the "Tech Stack" button should be disabled, grayed out, or removed. In my opinion, if a button is supposed to jump to certain content but is unable to because that content doesn't exist, the button should reflect that inability.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention! We'll get this one fixed, cheers!

Comment: @Courtny: Preferably disabled but still visible.  It is important to job seekers to know that the company was asked that question and decided not to provide the information.

Comment: We're on this. Let's hide the button altogether if there's no tech stack section (we're already doing this with the other buttons for the other sections).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for the report, Adam. This has been fixed!